# Nginx ssl configuration using certbot

Tags: nginx, ssl, certbot

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my setup. I used certbot to enable https on my website.

Attached is my nginx config

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 30;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        client_max_body_size 500M;
        client_body_timeout 600;
        client_header_timeout 600;
        client_body_buffer_size  25m;
        client_header_buffer_size 1m;

        large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;
        send_timeout 60;
        reset_timedout_connection on;

        open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
        open_file_cache_valid 30s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
        open_file_cache_errors off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_buffers 4 4k;
        gzip_types       text/html application/x-javascript text/css application/javascript text/javascript text/plain text/xml application/json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-opentype application/x-font-truetype application/x-font-ttf application/xml font/eot font/opentype font/otf image/svg+xml image/vnd.microsoft.icon;
        gzip_vary on;

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/sites/example.com/public;

        expires $expires;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error error;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

When I check if my port 443 is open

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-03-03 14:16 +08
Nmap scan report for example.com
Host is up (0.016s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp   open     http
443/tcp  open     https
```

Curl result

```
curl https://example.com/ -v
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to example.com:443
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to example.com:443
```

Another test

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -msg
CONNECTED(00000005)
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0139], ClientHello
    ...
write:errno=54
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 318 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
```

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: I did check /var/log/nginx/error.log and /var/log/nginx/example.error but could not find anything helpful. Anywhere else I should be looking at?

Comment: Is there certificate in /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem, and is not empty ?

Comment: yes. it has the following files: cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.pem  privkey.pem  README

Comment: And no, they are not empty.

Comment: added these 2 lines at the bottom of ssl_certificate_key. nginx restarted. Still getting the same error.

Comment: So what was in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

Please add to your nginx configuration:

```
ssl on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

Comment: Added these 2 lines right after ssl_certificate_key. Restarted nginx and still the same.

Comment: Have nginx access to this certificate ? If you are using redhat distributies, please turn off selinux at check time. nginx -t return all ok ?

Comment: nginx -t returns ok. im using ubuntu. how do i verify if nginx has access to this cert? when I `ls` it the display shows as `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem -> ../../archive/example.com/privkey1.pem`. I can verify the archive folder is accessible.

Comment: Change your nginx configuration to /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example.com/privkey1.pem and check this certificate via openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout

Comment: and? what was it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there are other config files in the `sites-enabled` directory which are causing the issue.

Deleting them and keeping only the file created resolved the issue for me.

By the way, CERTBOT automated redirect from HTTP to HTTPS does a really good job!